# Can I see the actual query generated when using OracleParameters with OracleCommand?

Tags: c#, sql, odp.net

I want to use ODP.NET to run various queries on an oracle database and I'd like to use parameters in the query. Here's a trivial example snippet (omitting all the obvious setup bits of the `OracleConnection`):

```
string query = "SELECT FIRSTNAME FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE LASTNAME=:pNAME";
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(query);
command.Parameters.Add(":pNAME", OracleDBType.Varchar2).Value = "O'Brien";
```

My question is, is there anyway to see the query that gets generated from this? I know this is a simple example and the output is probably very obvious, but I'm trying to see how it actually handles things like escaping characters such as the `'` in O`'Brien`. And of course in the future if my queries get more complicated and I'm getting sql errors, I thought I might be able to use the generated query to debug.

Any help or pointers is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL parameters are passed as parameters directly to SQL server, so there is no way to see it from your application. You can try checking it from Oracle side.

Comment: +1 Not the answer I was hoping for, but an answer nonetheless, thanks.